# CRM 2011: Set datetime field from string with javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, formatdatetime

I'm trying to create a new record where one of the fields is a DataTime field.

I always get the "The date-time format for Thu Sep 01 19:25:20 2011 is invalid, or value is outside the supported range." error.

I've tried multiple format options. With Date.parse, Date.parseExact, ... Here 's my last attempt:

```
//date input format = 2011-02-15 11:05:22

    var year = register_date.substring(0, 4);
    var month = register_date.substring(5, 7);
    var day = register_date.substring(8, 10);
    var hours = register_date.substring(11, 13);
    var minutes = register_date.substring(14, 16);
    var seconds = register_date.substring(17, 19);


    var datetime = Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes,seconds)); 

    //var datetime = Date.parseExact(register_date, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");

    regFields[4] = new CRMField("ave_subscriptiondate", datetime);
```

Comment: so the date format starts as `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`, but what to you want it to end up as?

Comment: also, where are you trying to create this record?

Comment: I'm trying to create a registration record for a course. Taking data from the an email record. (reading the xml in the body). I know that the subscriptiondate field is a datetime field. But i don't know in which format i should pass the date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the code below and you can just do:

```
datetime.toCRMFormat();
```

This code was found in this [useful CRM 2011 JS library](http://www.bizforward.cws-international.com/2011/03/09/useful-javascript-functions-and-methods-for-crm-2011-cws-crm-utils-js-library/)

```
// Formats the date to CRM format
Date.prototype.toCRMFormat = function()
{
    var d = this;
    var f = d.Format("yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss+" + (-d.getTimezoneOffset()/60) + ":00");

    return f;
}

// Formats the date into a certain format
Date.prototype.Format = function(format)
{
   var d = this;
   var f = "";

try {
    f = f + format.replace( /dd|mm|yyyy|MM|hh|ss|ms|APM|\s|\/|\-|,|\./ig , 
    function match()
    {
    switch(arguments[0])
    {
     case "dd": 
        var dd = d.getDate();
        return (dd < 10)? "0" + dd : dd;
     case "mm":
        var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
        return (mm < 10)? "0" + mm : mm; 
     case "yyyy": return d.getFullYear();
     case "hh": 
        var hh = d.getHours();
        return (hh < 10)? "0" + hh : hh;
     case "MM": 
        var MM = d.getMinutes(); 
        return (MM < 10)? "0" + MM : MM;
     case "ss": 
        var ss = d.getSeconds(); 
        return (ss < 10)? "0" + ss : ss;
     case "ms": return d.getMilliseconds();
     case "APM": 
        var apm = d.getHours(); 
        return (apm < 12)? "AM" : "PM";
     default: return arguments[0];
    }
    });
}
catch(err)
{
}

   return f;
}
```

Or if you want them as regular functions instead of extensions on Date such as `dateToCRMFormat(datetime)`

```
// Formats the date to CRM format
function dateToCRMFormat (date)
{
    return dateFormat(date, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss+" + (-date.getTimezoneOffset()/60) + ":00");
}


// Formats the date into a certain format
function dateFormat (date, format)
{
   var f = "";

try {
    f = f + format.replace( /dd|mm|yyyy|MM|hh|ss|ms|APM|\s|\/|\-|,|\./ig , 
    function match()
    {
    switch(arguments[0])
    {
     case "dd": 
        var dd = date.getDate();
        return (dd < 10)? "0" + dd : dd;
     case "mm":
        var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return (mm < 10)? "0" + mm : mm; 
     case "yyyy": return date.getFullYear();
     case "hh": 
        var hh = date.getHours();
        return (hh < 10)? "0" + hh : hh;
     case "MM": 
        var MM = date.getMinutes(); 
        return (MM < 10)? "0" + MM : MM;
     case "ss": 
        var ss = date.getSeconds(); 
        return (ss < 10)? "0" + ss : ss;
     case "ms": return date.getMilliseconds();
     case "APM": 
        var apm = date.getHours(); 
        return (apm < 12)? "AM" : "PM";
     default: return arguments[0];
    }
    });
}
catch(err)
{
}

   return f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Almost there i think, but  what is datetime in this answer?

Comment: It corresponds to the variable named the same in your code.  It's a javascript Date object that you want to convert to the format that CRM expects.

Comment: I get following error: Object doesn't support property or method 'toCRMFormat'

Comment: And you included the function below it?  I added a regular function you can call instead of adding it to the Date's prototype.  Give that a go.

Comment: It seems my data object doesn't know any method called Format or getTimeZoneOffset.. Should i import lib?

Comment: The [`getTimezoneOffset` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTimezoneOffset.asp) is part of the built in Date object.  The `Format` method came from [the library](http://www.bizforward.cws-international.com/download/crm/CWS.CRM.Utils.js) I linked to in the answer.  I'll update the answer to include that function too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have to use this many more times so your answer is very useful!. I finally used the extensions on Date.

Comment: in the stand-alone dateFormat version d.getFullYear() should be date.getFullYear() on line: case "yyyy": return d.getFullYear();