# Customize Campaign Form in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need to customize the **Campaign Form in Microsoft Dynamis CRM** .In this Form I need to customize the calender of Fiscal Year.it dispalys **mm/dd/yyy** format ..and i need to customize **MM/YYYY** Fromat.How to do this?

[image]

Comment: By the way, a very similar question is asked [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614029/how-to-set-textfield-only-with-month-and-year-from-calender-in-crm/15615013#15615013). Are you using two profiles? It's called [sockpuppetry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sock-puppets) and is strictly prohibited. You may get banned for just a suspicion of doing that. I'm not a snitch, so I won't report it but others may.

Answer (score 1):

This is only fot that field? The format of datetime is based on user options. If it's only for that field see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274115/crm-2011-set-datetime-field-from-string-with-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the date-time field is formatted according to the system settings (be that picked from CRM or the user's computer). Not sure if it's editable other than that. I'll take a look at it later today.

In case it's not possible to customize the date format of a single field you've got three options (listed in increasing order of control but also of implementation workload).

1. Set the system settings according to your wishes.
2. Add custom fields and control the looks in these.
3. Create a web resource that behaves exactly as you wish.