# How to set textfield only with Month and year from calender in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

After selecting calendar in campaign form , I need to set text field only display `Month/Year`
instead of `Day/Month/Year`. How can I do this?

I attached a screen shot below:
[image]

Here its `Day/Month/Year`, but I need `Month/Year`.

Comment: Is there any property with name Format or Custom format in datetime picker you are using?

Comment: By the way, a very similar question is asked [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613073/customize-campaign-form-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011). Are you using two profiles? It's called [sockpuppetry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sock-puppets) and is strictly prohibited. You may get banned for just a suspicion of doing that. I'm not a snitch, so I won't report it but others may.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the date-time field is formatted according to the system settings (be that picked from CRM or the user's computer). Not sure if it's editable other than that. I'll take a look at it later today.

In case it's not possible to customize the date format of a single field you've got three options (listed in increasing order of control but also of implementation workload).

1. Set the system settings according to your wishes.
2. Add custom fields and control the looks in these.
3. Create a web resource that behaves exactly as you wish.